# recursive CHOWN - how do I do this without terminal

Tags: 16.04, gui, ubuntu-gnome, chown

I avoid using the terminal whenever possible, but recently I had to take ownership of a folder, or subfiles and subfolders. The only help I found for this was on google using the terminal. How can I do this using the GUI??? I tried using the properties dialog but that didn't seem to work recursively even when clicking on the button to change the permissions on files and folders.